# HeapSort Algorythm from txt file to list of arrays doesn't Sort the numbers

Tags: c#, file, sorting, arraylist, heapsort

So I have to make HeapSort Algorythm for University using pseudocode I was given (only for heapsort). And I have to use input and output file. But for now I have only made input file which is working fine since it loads the txt file and writes down all the numbers in Console. So the problem is that after adding sorting methods to Main nothing changes. Also I decided to make a test for every method and all of them writes down my numbers once and that is it. I am not really good with sorting so it is hard for me to find the issue. Also because it is from pseudocode I had to use and no the code I could do for myself. So Do You know what cause thats issue that the sorting doesn't occure?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Zad4
{
    class Program
    {
        void Heapify(List<int> array, int i, int n)
        {
            int largest, temp;
            int parent = i; 
            int left = 2 * i + 1; 
            int right = 2 * i + 2; 

            if (left < n && array[left] > array[parent]) 
            {
                largest = left;
            }
            else
            {
                largest = parent;
            }

            if (right < n && array[right] > array[largest]) 
            {
                largest = right;
            }
            if (largest != i)
            {

                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[largest];
                array[largest] = temp;

                Heapify(array, largest, n);
            }

        }

        void BuildHeap(List<int> array, int n)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = (n - 1) / 2; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
                Heapify(array, i, n); 
            }

        }

        void HeapSort(List<int> array, int n)
        {
            int i, temp;
            for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
                temp = array[0];
                array[0] = array[n - 1];
                array[n - 1] = temp;

                n = n - 1;

                Heapify(array, 0, n);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            Program A = new Program();

            StreamReader myFile =
               new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\dawid\\Desktop\\C#\\Heapsort\\dane.txt");
            string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

            myFile.Close();

            char rc = (char)10;
            String[] listLines = myString.Split(rc);
            List<List<int>> listArrays = new List<List<int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < listLines.Length; i++)
            {
                List<int> array = new List<int>();
                String[] listInts = listLines[i].Split(' ');
                for (int j = 0; j < listInts.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (listInts[j] != "\r")
                    {
                        array.Add(Convert.ToInt32(listInts[j]));
                    }
                }
                listArrays.Add(array);

               A.BuildHeap(array, n);
               A.HeapSort(array, n);
            }

            foreach (List<int> array in listArrays)
            {
                foreach (int i in array)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use breakpoints, try to see what your code is doing and why your sorting is not working, it's the best advice I can give you, since your code is too big for me to read and I have no way to test it right now

Comment: I tested the program with slight changes. Instead of taking numbers from a txt file I made an int array with random elements and instead of doing 
  A.BuildHeap(array, n);
  A.HeapSort(array, n);                                                                                I did  that:                                                                        
A.BuildHeap(array, array.Length);
A.HeapSort(array, array.Length);                                                            And it actually worked, but after doing the same thing with list (array.Count) it didn't work. Any soulutions?

Comment: What I meant to say is: use breakpoints to check what value each variable is holding (this is called debug), or, if you want, log it by using Console.Write(variable you want to track); inside the loop and it will give you a idea of what is happening in your code.

Comment: I tried that already before and what happend is that all my loops where writing my txt file just once and that is it. But I found a solution finally.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found is just changing the way I read my txt file and the most important one was bad use of my methods. So that is how it looks now and it sorting well. Maybe I shouldn't ask a question since I got an answer on my own. But well. There You go:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program A = new Program();
        string[] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\dawid\Desktop\C#\Heapsort\dane.txt");
        int[] arrayInt = Array.ConvertAll(array, int.Parse);
        A.BuildHeap(arrayInt, arrayInt.Length);
        A.HeapSort(arrayInt, arrayInt.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arrayInt));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```